# How to allow scrolling in Android's PopupWindow

Tags: android, scroll, popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow that is populated with a LinearLayout.  I instatiated my popup window like this:

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 450, 700, true);
pw.showAsDropDown(layout, 80, 80);
```

However, when the device orientation is switched to landscape, the popup window gets cut off at the bottom and I cannot scroll down.  See the screen capture:
[image]

The layout underneath this popup is indeed scrollable.  So how can I make the popup scrollable?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinearLayouts aren't scrollable, so instead enclose the LinearLayout in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: I have a LinearLayout underneath the popup, and the popup itself is in a LinearLayout.  However, when I try to enclose the popup's code in a ScrollView, it just gets magnified and goes off the screen, but doesn't scroll.  Weird...

Comment: Besides that, I cannot have 2 ScrollViews like that.  I get an error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.ScrollView@40543ba0 has already been added to the window manager"

Comment: You need to use a new ScrollView instead of reusing an existing one.

Comment: I actually solved my problem by passing the screen width and height of the WindowManager to the PopupWindow constructor.  That way, I don't need to scroll - my popup just takes up the full screen.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

I do it using this and worked:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_popup"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#444444">

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it can be useful for you. Bye

Comment: Your LinearLayout is useless; you would enjoy a performance boost by replacing the root with the ScrollView.