# Android- EditText's text pushing other views down

Tags: android, android-edittext, view

I have an app in which the main view is a `PopupWindow` with a couple of `ImageViews` and an `EditText` on top of them. My problem is when I enter a very long text and the text box expands down and pushing the image views out of the view and I can't see them, and in order to see them back I need to delete some text.

What is the proper way of overcoming this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add into the XML something like that:

```
    android:maxLines = "5"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps enclosing your `LinearLayout` of the `PopupWindow` in a `ScrollView` could help.  `LinearLayout` does not allow for scrolling, if you are using it.

EDIT: In regards to the other answers, these will also work, but if you are intending to allow the user to enter as much text as they want, it may not be the best solution

See [This question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249442/how-to-allow-scrolling-in-androids-popupwindow)

Answer (score 0):

This should limit the height of the `EditText`, so even if the user types a long book in there, the field will keep its height limited to one line.

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

To limit the text to just one line, you can use this instead:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```